# vagrant+ansible: avoid downloading again from ansible-galaxy

Tags: ansible, vagrant, ansible-galaxy

In my `Vagrantfile` I have something similar to:

```
  config.vm.provision "ansible" do |ansible|
    ansible.playbook = "provisioning/main.yml"
    ansible.galaxy_role_file = "provisioning/requirements.yml"
  end
```

`provisioning/requirements.yml` contains some roles that are fetch from ansible-galaxy.

Every time `vagrant provision` is executed, all roles are downloaded again. Is there a way to avoid redownloading every single time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change the default [`galaxy_command`](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/provisioning/ansible_common.html#galaxy_command) and remove the `--force` option. Something like

```rb
config.vm.provision "ansible" do |ansible|
  ansible.playbook = "provisioning/main.yml"
  ansible.galaxy_role_file = "provisioning/requirements.yml"
  ansible.galaxy_command = "ansible-galaxy install --role-file=%{role_file} --roles-path=%{roles_path}"
end
```

Be aware though that roles will not update once installed and you will have to manage that manually.